# Is the composition of two homeomorphisms a homeomorphism?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, analysis, differential-topology

Suppose $f : X \rightarrow Z $ and $g : Z \rightarrow Y $ functions and:
$$f : X \rightarrow f(X) \subset Z \quad \text{and} \quad g : Z \rightarrow g(Z) \subset Y $$
are homeomorphisms.

**Is it true that:**
$$f : K \subset X \rightarrow f(K)$$
and
$$g\circ f : X  \rightarrow g \circ f(X)$$
are also a homeomorphisms?
If so why?

**Definition** A fuction $f:X \rightarrow Y$ is a homeomorphism if $f$ is bijective , contentious and it's inverse is also continuous.

**My intuition**
If $$f : X \rightarrow f(X) \subset Z$$ is a homeomorphism then $f(X) \cap Z = f(X)$, so if the first part of my question is true, then $$g:f(X) \rightarrow g(f(X))$$ is a homeomorphism, So

$$g \circ f : X \rightarrow (g \circ f)(X)$$
Is indeen a homeomorphism.

What do you think?

Comment: The title says *homomorphisms*, the question use *homeomorphisms*. You should correct the typo. Also, I think you meant *continuous* instead of *contentious*, right?

Comment: You can separate the proof in three parts:
1) Prove that the composition of bijections is also a bijectios.
2) Prove that the composition of continuous function is also continuous.
3) Observa that $(g \circ f)^{-1} = f^{-1} \circ g^{-1}$  and by hypothesis $f^{-1}$ and $g^{-1}$ are continuous, so it reduces to case 2.

Comment: @Didier Yes thenk you!!

Comment: This is true. If $f : X \to Y$ and $g : Y \to Z$ are homeomorphisms, then $(g \circ f)^{-1} = f^{-1} \circ g^{-1}$ is a composition of continuous functions, hence continuous. The same is true of $g \circ f$.

Answer (score 1):

There are points some to clarify. If you suppose $f : X \rightarrow Z $ and $g : Z \rightarrow Y $ functions and:
$$f : X \rightarrow f(X) \subset Z \quad \text{and} \quad g : Z \rightarrow g(Z) \subset Y $$
are homeomorphisms. Written as is what you say is that $f$ and $g$ are two [embedding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedding) maps. So they are homeomorphism onto its image. So it meants they the are in general injective, not bijective. So what you can prove is that composition of embedding is an embedding which is true. It is also true that composition of homeomorphisms is an homeomorphism. What I wanted to remark is that embedding as you wrote are not Homeomorphism in general. Those are very different notions. Usually you embed something, a manifold M for instance in $\Bbb R^n$.